# How to combine values from multiple rows of a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got one table with bank accounts where're many copies of same number like showed:

```
SELECT
    k1.Account_number, COUNT(*) as Counter
FROM
    Customers k1
GROUP BY
    k1.Account_number
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
order by Counter
```

Gives:

```
Account_number                         Counter
DE1234567891234566786545                  3
FR8734280472398472394823                  4
IT48723849y3294723493284                  4
IT3543534534423421321323                  4
FR4798237492864239847329                  6
FR4723984793284723984732                  7
```

What I need is to put one more column with the number of customers that have got this account.
I tried this:

```
STUFF((select '; ' + Customer_name from Customers FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') [Some_column]
```

But it puts all customers from that table :(

Comment: Sorry for grammar, English is not my native language.
Is there any chance to see how did you edited my table of results? I tried "space" but didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may work for you

```
SELECT
    k1.Account_number, COUNT(*) as Counter
    ,STUFF((SELECT ','+Customer_name FROM Customers K2 WHERE K2.Account_number= k1.Account_number FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM
    Customers k1
GROUP BY
    k1.Account_number
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
order by Counter
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I thought I missed something in subquery.
Thanks!

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting answers rewards the contributor and helps those that follow you to find a working solution.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You want a correlation clause in the subquery:

```
SELECT k1.Account_number, COUNT(*) as Counter,
       STUFF( (SELECT '; ' + c2.Customer_name 
               FROM Customers c2
               WHERE c2.Account_number = k1.Account_Number
               FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as Customers
FROM Customers k1
GROUP BY k1.Account_number
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY Counter
```